# Add array form data in google sheets api through PHP

Tags: php, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using google sheets API in PHP to add my html form data in google spreadsheet.
All other data have been appended in the respective cell of the sheet since each value had single data except one data which is in array since the html input data is in multiple checkbox.

My google sheet form:

[image]

And my code in php :

```
<?php

//add data to google spreadsheet
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

//getting form data
    $name_kanji = $_POST['name_kanji'];
    $name_katakana = $_POST['name_katakana'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $userEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $zip_code = $_POST['zip_code'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $address1 = $_POST['address1'];
    $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
    $experience = $_POST['experience'];
    $others_text = $_POST['others_text'];
    $lessons = $_POST['check_list'];
    $source = $_POST['source'];

//Reading data from spreadsheet.

$client = new \Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName('Google Sheets and PHP');

$client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);

$client->setAccessType('offline');

$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/credentials.json');

$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);


$spreadsheetId = "14B0iB8-uLFNkb_d0qY183wNXeW5reAW5QBjOf69VXeU"; //It is present in the spreadsheet URL

//Adding the data in your google sheet

$update_range = 'data';

$values = [[ $name_kanji, $name_katakana, $age, $phone, $userEmail, $zip_code.', '.$city.', '.$address1.', '.$address2, $experience, $others_text, $lessons, $source]];

$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
'values' => $values
]);

$params = [
'valueInputOption' => 'RAW'
];

$insert = [
    'insertDataOption' => 'INSERT_ROWS'
];

$update_sheet = $service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $update_range, $body, $params);
```

My problem is in following code

```
$values = [[ $name_kanji, $name_katakana, $age, $phone, $userEmail, $zip_code.', '.$city.', '.$address1.', '.$address2, $experience, $others_text, $lessons, $source]];
```

Here $lessons is in array whose data should be populated either by comma or in list in I column of the spreadsheet.

Can I get solution on how to pass the array data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To convert your array to a comma separate string use e.g. the [implode method](https://www.php.net/implode)

Sample:

```php
$list = implode(', ', $lessons);
$values = [[ $name_kanji, $name_katakana, $age, $phone, $userEmail, $zip_code.', '.$city.', '.$address1.', '.$address2, $experience, $others_text, $list, $source]];
```

Comment: It worked but how can I break the line instead of using comma? The html tag for breaking the line is displayed like comma instead of breaking the line.

Comment: For line break use `'\n'` instead of  `', '` as a separator.

Comment: The data will appear like this
data1\ndata2\ndata3\ndata4
in google sheet if I replace ```,``` by ```\n```

Comment: This is not my experience. In the spreadsheet the newlines are recognized and displayed correctly.